# Change the color of IntelliJ IDEA's cursor line

Tags: intellij-idea

I use chroMaterial and I have changed my background color but I can't change color when cursor is target.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked in the user documentation? There's a Fonts & Colors option menu where you can configure this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to:

- `Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme > General`
- Then click on `Caret row`
- Then change the `Background`

Here's a screen shot showing how/where to make the choice (in this example I have chosen red for my caret row):

[image]

Here's a screenshot showing the result of that choice:

[image]

Comment: For the latest IDEs (e.g., 2020), you will find it under `Editor > Caret row`.

Comment: new path is `Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Editor > Caret row`